# ArrayList from Fragment to Activity then to another Fragment

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-fragments

When I delete from the mMovements ArrayList in the onCreateView method of WODListFragment, I call setMovements from WODListActivity and pass in the updated ArrayList (successfully).

```
public class WODListFragment extends ListFragment{
public static final String NEW_MOVE_ADDED = "new_move_in_list";
public static final String MOVE_REMOVED = "move_removed";

private ArrayList<Integer> mMovements;

public static WODListFragment newInstance(ArrayList<Integer> moves) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putSerializable(NEW_MOVE_ADDED, moves);
    Log.d("fmovements", "size: " + moves.size());
    WODListFragment fragment = new WODListFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);

    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getActivity().setTitle(R.string.movement_title);

    // Get the arguments that were serialized in WODListActivity.
    Bundle args = getArguments();
    mMovements = (ArrayList<Integer>) args.getSerializable(NEW_MOVE_ADDED);

    MovementsAdapter adapter = new MovementsAdapter(mMovements);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.wod_list, parent, false);

    // get the amount of total movements allowed in the wod
    Intent i = getActivity().getIntent();
    int moveCount = i.getExtras().getInt("count");

    final Button finalize_wod = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.finalize_wod);
    final Button delete_move = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.delete_move);
    final TextView wod_scoring = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.wod_scoring);
    final Button start_wod = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.start_wod);

    // show finalize button when wod is full
    if (mMovements.size() == moveCount) {
        finalize_wod.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    // set finalize button
    finalize_wod.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // change visible buttons on finalize click
            finalize_wod.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            delete_move.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            wod_scoring.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            start_wod.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            Movement m = new Movement();

            if (mMovements.size() == 3) { // 3x3
                wod_scoring.setText(m.scoringExpl[0]);
            } 
            else if (mMovements.size() == 2) { // 21-15-9
                wod_scoring.setText(m.scoringExpl[1]);
            } 
            else // max effort
                wod_scoring.setText(m.scoringExpl[2]);

            // set start wod button
            start_wod.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // access stopwatch so user can start their wod
                }
            }); // end of start_wod setOnClickListener
        }
    }); // end of finalize_wod setOnClickListener


    // set delete button
    delete_move.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "delete",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mMovements.remove(mMovements.size() - 1);

            // update the listView with the value deleted
            ((MovementsAdapter)getListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();

            Activity activity = getActivity();

            if(activity instanceof WODListActivity) {
                ((WODListActivity) activity).setMovements(mMovements);
            }

            finalize_wod.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }); // end of delete_move setOnClickListener

    return v;
}

public class MovementsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Integer> {
    public MovementsAdapter(ArrayList<Integer> movements) {
        super(getActivity(), 0, movements);
        Log.d("testing", "here" + " " + movements.size());
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater()
                    .inflate(R.layout.wod_list_item, null);
        }

        final int move = getItem(position);
        TextView movementName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.movement_list_item_name);
        TextView movementReps = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.movement_list_item_reps);
        Button aboutMove = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnViewAbout);

        Movement m = new Movement();
        movementName.setText("Movement: " + m.movementNames[move]);
        movementReps.setText("Reps: " + m.reps[move]);

        // set about button
        aboutMove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent describeMov = new Intent(v.getContext(), MovementDescriptionActivity.class);

                describeMov.putExtra("id", move);
                startActivity(describeMov);
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

}

```
public class WODListActivity extends SingleFragmentActivity{

ArrayList<Integer> movements = new ArrayList<Integer>();

@Override
protected Fragment createFragment() {
    movements.addAll((Collection<? extends Integer>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(WODListFragment.NEW_MOVE_ADDED));

    return WODListFragment.newInstance(movements);
}

@Override 
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    setMovements(movements);
}

public void setMovements(ArrayList<Integer> moves) {

    Log.d("amovements", "size: " + moves.size());
    Intent data = new Intent();
    data.putExtra(WODListFragment.NEW_MOVE_ADDED, moves);
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);
}
```

}

I am trying to get this ArrayList back to MovementSelectionFragment and set the movements ArrayList to the updated ArrayList.  In WODListActivity it is passed in as the moves ArrayList.  I tried modifying the onActivityResult method in MovementSelectionFragment (along with about 100 different combinations of other things).  I also tried modifying the onPause method in WODListActivity.  Anyway, I'm frustrated and I need to hear some different perspectives.

```
public class MovementSelectionFragment extends Fragment{

private static final int REQUEST_NEW_MOVEMENT = 0;
public static final String NEW_MOVE_ADDED = "new_move_in_list";
public static final String MOVE_REMOVED = "move_removed";

private int numSelLeft;
private int origCount;
private GridView mGridView;
Boolean moveDel = false;
/*
 * This array allows the user to select multiple workouts at once. 
 * It doesn't need to be reinstantiated every time the user backs up
 * to this view.
 */
private ArrayList<Integer> movements = new ArrayList<Integer>();

 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

 @Override 
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.movement_selection, parent, false);

    // display number of moves in wod
    if (movements.isEmpty()) {
        numSelLeft = displayBeforeSelect(v);
        origCount = numSelLeft;
    }

    // locate gridView and assign ImageAdapter
    mGridView = (GridView)v.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    mGridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(v.getContext()));

    mGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position,
                long id) {

            // Sending image id to WODListActivity
            Intent movementIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(),
                    WODListActivity.class);
            movements.add(position); // Add position of movement to array

            v.setVisibility(View.GONE); // kill selected button

            movementIntent.putExtra(WODListFragment.NEW_MOVE_ADDED,
                    movements);
            movementIntent.putExtra("count", origCount);
            startActivityForResult(movementIntent, REQUEST_NEW_MOVEMENT);
        }

    });

    return v;
 } 

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        return;
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: have you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store your `Adapter` in `Activity` as a field, make a getter to it and access it in fragments via, for example, `(WODListActivity) getActivity().getMovementsAdapter();`